# How can I put a button inside text without line-breaks occuring?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I would like to put a button inside text like this one:

```
some text1 [button] some text2.
```

However if I place form&input, line break occures before and after my button like this:

```
some text1
[button]
some text2
```

I know I can do this with tables, but I want to avoid it. Is there any CSS based solution to do this? Unfortunately, I can't modify the HTML code, so I have to "inject" that little form statement (with input type submit, and some hidden input tags too) in the generated HTML (done by other software), so it would be hard to reformat it, using tables, etc.

Is it even legal to put form/input tags within text which is enclosed between 'p' tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried giving the button a class then give the class a `display: inline;` in your CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're injecting a form that contains a button into some text and the `form` tag is causing the text to wrap (`form` is a block level element). This is a simple fix with CSS:

**HTML:**

```
some text <form><button>test</button></form> some text
```

**CSS:**

```
form
{
    display:inline;
}
```

If you don't want to make a blanket change to all the form elements, simply assign the injected form a CSS class:

**HTML:**

```
some text <form class="inlineForm"><button>test</button></form> some text
```

**CSS:**

```
.inlineForm
{
    display:inline;
}
```

**Alternative:**

You could also add `display:inline` directly to the form tag:

```
some text <form style="display:inline"><button>test</button></form> some text
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/85Lmk/)

Answer (score 7):

The css solution is `white-space:nowrap`. Wrap it with a span tag with that rule.  For example, assuming you have this rule in the your css file:

```
.nowrap {
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

You can do it with this html:

```
<span class="nowrap">some text1 <button>test</button> some text2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `style="display:inline"` to the form tag

```
hello <form  style="display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="blah"/><input type="submit" /></form>world
```

gives

```
hello [button] world
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make all blocks among your text - inline.

like that:

```
<form style="display: inline">
```

If there are divs after your form, make them inline too